# (angular 6) Graphic bug on opening a right sidenav

Tags: angular, angular-material, transition

I use 2 sidenav 1 left and 1 right, they have exactly the same basic code and the right sidenav bug randomly when I open it.

This bug appears only when the sidenav have the `mode` set to `over` and when the position is at the end, the left sidenav works perfectly.

```html
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">

      <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="over">
        Sidenav content
      </mat-sidenav>

      <mat-sidenav #right mode="over" position="end">
        Sidenav content
      </mat-sidenav>

      <mat-sidenav-content>
        <header>
          <topbar (changeleftside)="sideBarLeftEvent($event);" (changerightside)="sideBarRightEvent($event);"></topbar>
       </header>
        <p><button mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">sidenav.toggle()</button></p>
        <p><button mat-button (click)="right.toggle()">sid.toggle()</button></p>
      </mat-sidenav-content>

</mat-sidenav-container>
```

and just a transition in css :

```css
mat-sidenav 
{
     transition: 0.6s all;
}
```

I have this issue on Chrome and Firefox works better but it appears sometimes.

Here's a video where you can see this bug :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMZXid5eYWY&feature=youtu.be

thanks for your time!

Comment: Copy paste your code in your post. Don't put screenshots.

Comment: Yes ok, sorry first time i post.